# How to get/display the total length of the array object in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to get/display the total `length` of the `PENDING` and `REJECTED` in angular

if `status === 'PENDING'` else if `status === 'REJECTED`

here's the code:

***list.components.ts***

```
const group: any = groupBy(params, 'status');

    Object.values(group).map((x: any) => {
      x.map((key: any) => {
        console.log(key);
      });
```

here's the `array`

```
{
          "assetcode": "001", "assetname": "Machine Print", "assettype": "Type", "floorcode": "58",
          "linecode": "02", "rowNo": 0, "lastpmdate": "2019-12-02 08:00:00", "status": "PENDING"
        },
        {
          "assetcode": "002", "assetname": "Machine Print", "assettype": "Type", "floorcode": "58",
          "linecode": "02", "rowNo": 0, "lastpmdate": "2019-12-02 08:00:00", "status": "PENDING"
        },
        {
          "assetcode": "003", "assetname": "Machine Print-V2", "assettype": "Type", "floorcode": "58",
          "linecode": "03", "rowNo": 0, "lastpmdate": "2019-12-02 08:00:00", "status": "PENDING"
        },
        {
          "assetcode": "003", "assetname": "Machine Print-V2", "assettype": "Type", "floorcode": "58",
          "linecode": "03", "rowNo": 0, "lastpmdate": "2019-12-02 08:00:00", "status": "PENDING"
        },
        {
          "assetcode": "003", "assetname": "Machine Print-V2", "assettype": "Type", "floorcode": "58",
          "linecode": "03", "rowNo": 0, "lastpmdate": "2019-12-02 08:00:00", "status": "PENDING"
        },
        {
          "assetcode": "003", "assetname": "Machine Print-V2", "assettype": "Type", "floorcode": "58",
          "linecode": "03", "rowNo": 0, "lastpmdate": "2019-12-02 08:00:00", "status": "PENDING"
        },
        {
          "assetcode": "003", "assetname": "Machine Print-V2", "assettype": "Type", "floorcode": "58",
          "linecode": "03", "rowNo": 0, "lastpmdate": "2019-12-02 08:00:00", "status": "REJECTED"
        },
        {
          "assetcode": "003", "assetname": "Machine Print-V2", "assettype": "Type", "floorcode": "58",
          "linecode": "03", "rowNo": 0, "lastpmdate": "2019-12-04 08:00:00", "status": "REJECTED"
        },
        {
          "assetcode": "003", "assetname": "Machine Print-V2", "assettype": "Type", "floorcode": "58",
          "linecode": "03", "rowNo": 0, "lastpmdate": "2019-12-03 08:00:00", "status": "PENDING"
        },
```

here's the `group`

```
{PENDING: Array(6), REJECTED: Array(1)}
PENDING: Array(6)
0: {assetcode: "001", assetname: "Machine Print", assettype: "Type", floorcode: "58", linecode: "02", …}
1: {assetcode: "002", assetname: "Machine Print", assettype: "Type", floorcode: "58", linecode: "02", …}
2: {assetcode: "003", assetname: "Machine Print-V2", assettype: "Type", floorcode: "58", linecode: "03", …}
3: {assetcode: "003", assetname: "Machine Print-V2", assettype: "Type", floorcode: "58", linecode: "03", …}
4: {assetcode: "003", assetname: "Machine Print-V2", assettype: "Type", floorcode: "58", linecode: "03", …}
5: {assetcode: "003", assetname: "Machine Print-V2", assettype: "Type", floorcode: "58", linecode: "03", …}
length: 6
REJECTED: Array(1)
0: {assetcode: "003", assetname: "Machine Print-V2", assettype: "Type", floorcode: "58", linecode: "03", …}
length: 1
{PENDING: Array(2)}
PENDING: Array(2)
0: {assetcode: "003", assetname: "Machine Print-V2", assettype: "Type", floorcode: "58", linecode: "03", …}
1: {assetcode: "003", assetname: "Machine Print-V2", assettype: "Type", floorcode: "58", linecode: "03", …}
length: 2;
{REJECTED: Array(1)}
REJECTED: Array(1)
0: {assetcode: "003", assetname: "Machine Print-V2", assettype: "Type", floorcode: "58", linecode: "03", …}
length: 1
```

console
[image]

total `length` is `10`
there's `8` for `PENDING` and `2` for `REJECTED`

it should be display like this

```
 if (key.status === 'PENDING') {
     /// the output should be 8
    } else if (key.status === 'REJECTED') {
 /// the output should be 2
}
```

Comment: It seems like the salient question is how to get the total number of items in an array that fit a certain criteria, no?  Seems like you could just use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and take the length of the result?  I'm not sure that we actually need to concern ourselves with the fact that this takes place in an Angular context... unless I'm misunderstanding the question/issue...

Comment: There is no `status` in the screenshot added. What do `params` and `group` look like? Please create a [mcve] by adding the actual data as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `group` is that array that you have the screenshot attached:

```
const pending = group.filter(asset => asset.status === 'PENDING').length;
const rejected = group.filter(asset => asset.status === 'REJECTED').length;
```

`filter` does the filtering by status, and `length` returns the total number of filtered items.

If you have multiple arrays, you can first concatenate them using `concat()` to get a single array:

```
var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
var children = hege.concat(stale);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

*Note:*

In your original code, you are doing `groupBy()` to create a new object with two keys (pending and rejected), but you don't even need that because `filter` will do what you need, and with concat you can merge multiple arrays into one.

Comment: how'bout when there's 4 array

Comment: I updated the answer for multiple arrays. It's a separate action: you need to concat your arrays into a single one first, then do the 2 filters. It's really outside of the original question you asked, but I hope it helped. I also added a note about your use of groupBy. If this answer helped, please don't forget to upvote/accept it.